# Equillibrium Position of Partition

Tags: thermodynamics, photons, pressure, thermal-radiation, radiation-pressure

Suppose You have a cylinder with its surface insulated and there is a partition that is free to move. You put a photon gas on both sides of a partition, and You have managed to make the temperature of both sides to be different by attaching each side (that is circular cross-section of a cylinder) to the heat bath.

The radiation pressure of photon gas depends only on temperature, that implies that there will be different pressure on both side of the partition. So How the equilibrium state will attain if pressure only depends on temperature?

Answer (score 0):

The zeroth law of thermodynamics states that two systems have the same temperature if and only if they are in thermodynamic equilibrium. If you have a system where you have fixed different parts at different temperatures, then those different parts cannot reach equilibrium, by definition.

Comment: The OP means the force equilibrium. not the thermal equilirium.

Comment: thermodynamic equilibrium require force equilibrium. The fact that it is manifesting here as a pressure gradient does not really matter. The general idea is that this system is forced not to equilibriate by its construction, so it is not surprising that it doesn't

Comment: But, force equlibrium doesn't require thermal equlibrium. For instance, adding friction to the piston to stop moving.

Comment: Consider the same for ideal gas instead of photon gas, and you will get my point.

Comment: I see your point. I could possibly rephrase my answer as "why do find the fact that this system does not reach equilibrium surprising?"

Answer (score 0):

Say that the photons are coming from the black body radition of the walls of the cylinder. The higher temperature part render a larger photon pressure, and therefore push the piston toward the side of lower temperature.

Different from the gas pressure and volume concept. The photon number is not conserved. The longer the side-length will provide more resonace modes. The photon number will increase in accordance to the increasing in length.

Therefore, without friction, the lower temperature part will be deminished.